# How can function overloading and the ODR coexist? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, compilation, overloading, one-definition-rule

Why doesn't defining multiple functions of the same name in a compilation unit violate the One Definition Rule? How does the compiler identify between code that violates the ODR and code in which function overloading is used?

Comment: You are asking two very different Q. 1) What is the ODR, how it applies to overloaded functions? 2) When is overloading good practice? (The ODR doesn't just apply to one compilation unit, it applies to the whole program BTW.)

Comment: Functions with the same name but different parameters are different functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the definition *includes* the parameter types (and since C++ 17, the exception specifications).

So, overloading is possible because the functions are not the same even if the name is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The One Definition Rule means that each overloaded function must be defined once. So there is no contradiction.  Each overloaded function differs in some way for example the number or types of parameters, presence or absence c/v qualifiers (in parameter declarations or of class member functions themselves) and so on.

Sometimes beginners consider for example these function declarations as declarations of overloaded functions

```
void f( int a[100] );
void f( int a[10] );
void f( int a[] );
void f( int *a );
```

However the compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter of an array type to pointer of the array element type.

You may include all these (redundant) declarations in your program but must define the function only once.

So the declarations above declare the same one function the parameters of which are adjusted by the compiler to the type `int *`.

Take into account that these function declarations declare two overloaded functions

```
void f( int *a );
void f( const int *a );
```

(here the pointer itself is not constant it is the data pointed to by the pointer is constant)

while these two declarations

```
void f( int x );
void f( const int x );
```

declare the same one function because the const qualifier is discarded when the compiler determines whether functions are overloaded or are the same.

The same confusion can arise when a function parameter has a function type. For example

```
void f( void g() );
void f( void ( *g )() );
```

Again the compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter of a function type to pointer to the function.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void f( void g() );
void f( void ( *g )() );

void g() { std::cout << "Hello Philippa Richter\n"; }

void f( void g() )
{
    g();
}

int main()
{
    f( g );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello Philippa Richter
```

Pay attention to that the function `f` is defined once though it is declared three times including the declaration that at the same time is its definition.

Answer (score 0):

The One Definition Rule does *not* apply to things having the same name; it applies to things pretending to be the same.

Two classes named `foo` (declared at global scope, that is outside a namespace, or class, or function) pretend to be the same; they have to be the same. You lie to the compiler if you change the definitions in one program. (That's like arguing with someone based on peculiar definitions of terms and then pretend to have proven something applying to the regular terms.)

Two functions named `bar` don't pretend to be the same unless they have the same parameter lists.